# Using Arduino LED instead of LiPo charger (TP4056) CHRG + STDBY LEDs

Tags: arduino, tp4056

I want to remove the LEDs (RED+GRN) on the charger PCB and indicate if the battery is charging on the Arduino 33 BLE Sense board instead. Arduino has a bad habit of reporting random numbers on the input ports when there's nothing connected. And the gates to the existing LEDs are opened to ground (?) so I'm guessing I need a converter or transistor that converts the grounded signal to a positive one?

[image: LiPo charger with LEDs that I want to replace with digital/analog signal to Arduino]

Comment: The only crappy datasheet of "TP4056" I could find doesn't mention how much those pins can sink. The current depends a lot on the LED forward voltages. I wouldn't use "Alibaba" integrated circuits where the datasheet is a joke.

Comment: "Arduino has a bad habit of reporting random numbers on the input ports when there's nothing connected." Where are the input ports in this schematic?

Comment: @Lundin I have not replaced the LEDs in the sketch with input ports because I don't know how to do it. Do you have a better alternative for TP4056? I'm not buying because it's cheap - it just because I don't know better and I found some examples using it.

Comment: There's a whole lot of charger ICs out there, just pick a well-known brand. Anyway, if you just wish to replace the LEDs with two input pins then that's easy, just connect them. You just need pull-up resistors, internal or external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lundin pointed out, just make the connection directly to the Arduino board. My suggestion is to replace the LEDs with 10k resistors, as in the modification shown below. The voltage to the Arduino inputs should be at VCC when the LEDs would normally be OFF, and near zero volts when ON, so an inverted logic that you can correct in software. Be sure that the Arduino is compatible with VCC, and if not then add two more resistors to drop the voltage (connecting to each Arduino input to ground).

[image]